# Is there a way to log the module that Visual Studio loads?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am encountering a big performance problem when building lately, and I suspect that it's some sort of add-on problem.

Disabling all my extensions did not help.  However, running vs in safemode (devenv /safemode) helped a great deal.

Now I just need to figure out what was different between VS running in safe mode vs. running normally.  Is there a better way to diagnose this performance problem?

Comment: Did you disable all add-ons as well? Resharper? Any macros?

Comment: Yep -- we did finally find an alternate solution here: http://www.netusup.com/2010/11/15/silverlight-build-slow-with-wcf-ria-services/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick google search and came up with the following:

"There’s a built-in command line switch devenv.exe /log to log Visual Studio activity, e.g. which packages got loaded, etc. "

Comment: Not sure how I managed to miss that when I typed devenv /?, but sure enough, there it is.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, most versions of Visual Studio accept a `/SafeMode` option to start without all the extensions/plugins